# Identify gradient text colors in pdf file

Tags: pdf, gradient

I have a pdf file with a gradient text header.
Is it any way that I can identify which colors the gradient text?
I want to be able to use the same gradient on my own, like in a word document.

Best regards

Comment: I have a pdf file with a gradient text header. Is it any way that I can identify which colors the gradient text uses? I want to be able to use the same gradient on my own, like in a word document. * Sorry for the typo.

Comment: *"Sorry for the typo."* - you can edit your question, there is an [edit] link right underneath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Photoshop (or any other app which has color pick functionality) to get color code from image,pdf...

[image]